# iOS style notifications on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

I have a simple app developed in Kotlin for Android phones. It receives a (data) message from my server when a specific event occurs. I want the phone to show a notification message when this happens. I would like the notification to behave similar to how iOS notifications work. If the user is using the phone (using the app itself, another app, or on the homescreen) then a heads-up message should appear with the message content from the server (just a text string). If the phone screen is off and/or locked, then a notification should appear on the notification area (expanded, not just showing an icon) and the screen should turn on. I have tried several solutions but I just don't seem to get it to work properly. What is the simplest solution to this problem?

This is my messaging service.

```kotlin
...  
  
class NotificationService : FirebaseMessagingService() {  
  
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {  

        remoteMessage.data.let {  
            it["my_alert"]?.let { body -> sendNotification(body) }  
        }        remoteMessage.notification?.let {  
            it.body?.let { body -> sendNotification(body) }  
        }  
    private fun getRemoteView(messageBody: String) : RemoteViews {  
        val remoteView = RemoteViews(applicationContext.packageName, R.layout.notification)  
        remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.message, messageBody)  
        return remoteView  
    }
    
    private fun sendNotification(messageBody: String) {  
        val channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id)  
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager  
        val requestCode = 0  
        val contentIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        val contentPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, contentIntent, 0)  
        val fullScreenIntent = Intent(this, LockscreenActivity::class.java)  
        val fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(  
            this,  
            requestCode,  
            fullScreenIntent,  
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT  
        )  
  
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {  
            val channel = NotificationChannel(  
                channelId,  
                "My alerts",  
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH,  
            )  
            channel.description = "Notifications description."  
            channel.setShowBadge(false)  
            channel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC  
            channel.enableVibration(true)  
            channel.vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(200, 200, 200, 200, 200)  
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)  
            Log.d(TAG,"Channel created.")  
        }  
        val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)   
  
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId) 
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)  
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.alert_title))  
            .setContentText(messageBody)  
            //.setContent(getRemoteView(messageBody))  
            //.setCustomHeadsUpContentView(getRemoteView(messageBody))  
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)  
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)  
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true) 
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)  
            .setContentIntent(contentPendingIntent)  
            //.setPublicVersion(publicNotification)  
            .setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent, true)            
            .setAutoCancel(true)  
  
  
        val notification = notificationBuilder.build()  
  
        val notificationId = 0  
        notificationManager.cancelAll()  
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification)  
  
    }  
}
```

I have left a few commented lines in there so you can kind of see what else I have tried. I'll be happy to supply any additional information if needed.
In my `LockscreenActivity` I have added `setShowWhenLocked(true)` and `setTurnScreenOn(true)`. This works, but it displays the entire layout in full screen (which I guess makes sense, but it's not what I want). Although the cases when the phone is not locked or screen turned off, it works like I expect (a head-up message). If I don't use the custom activity `LockscreenActivity` then I can't get the screen to turn on. I am a bit confused on the details here, but I still want the `MainActivity` to be launched when the user taps the notification, so I assume that `setContentIntent()` should still point to `MainActivity`. It doesn't seem to work to put `setShowWhenLocked(true)` and `setTurnScreenOn(true)` in `MainActivity`, so I assume I must have a specific activity that is used AS the notification, but how can I get this to show up only as a heads-up and not fill the entire screen? The layout XML for `LockscreenActivity` looks as follows.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">

        
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/app_logo"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_notification"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/app_logo"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Message"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/app_logo"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you add a screenshot on how are you seeing this "but it displays the entire layout in full screen"? Additionally, did you try using constraint layout wrapping the height to the content?

Comment: It fills the entire screen when the notification arrives (testing with a Samsung phone). https://imgur.com/a/gznAjNB

Comment: I also tried now to use constraint layout as you suggested, but it also fills the entire screen like the relative layout.

Comment: I also tried setting `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` to some specific dp value, instead of `match_parent`, but it still shows in fullscreen.